# Apply variable to the loop ERROR-"For Each can only iterate over a collection object or an array"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a table to organize my studies, I have a worksheet with a combox with the values Comcluido, In Progress and Not Started.
When selected it activates my markStatus function that receives as a parameter the day that will be marked, and the status value.

I'm having trouble assigning the value of the month dynamically to my loop. Since the loop only runs correctly after passing
the parameter explicitly

*Explicitly:*

```
...
    For Each Cell In [january]
       'Action
...
```

*Dynamically:*

```
...
    For Each Cell In [month (2)]
        'Action
...
```

**Return:**
Compilation error:
For Each can only iterate over a collection object or an array

I tried to search as a reference in the documentation and some tutorials but I can't come up with a solution.
Can you help me ?

```
Public Function mes(refMonth As Integer)
    'Returns the month in full
    Dim months As Variant
    months = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "December")
    month = months(refMonth - 1)

End Function

 
Public Sub markStatus(dayRef, status)
    Dim currMonth As String
    Set nms = ActiveWorkbook.Names
    
    currMonth = month(8)
    
    For n = 1 To nms.Count

        For Each Cell In [currMonth]  
            If dayRef = Cell.Value Then
                
                Sheets("Calendar").Activate
                ActiveSheet.Range(Cell.Address).Offset(1, 0).Select
                 
                If (status = "Concluded") Then
                    Call Concluded 'Styles my cell
                    
                ElseIf (status = "In Progress") Then
                    Call InProgress ' Styles my cell
                    
                End If
                
            End If
        Next Cell
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: use: `For Each Cell In Range(currMonth)`

Comment: It returned: The "Range 'method of the object" _Worksheet "failed.
`[currMonth]`-  represents a set of cells that make up the month, I used the name attribute to refer to it

Comment: you cannot use `[]` with  a variable.  is the named range worksheet or workbook scope?

Comment: I think workbook scope, I'm not sure why I didn't understand the question
I used this video as a reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=629dqqN3gCc&t=337s&ab_channel=ExcelVbaIsFun

Comment: if workbook then `For Each Cell In Range(currMonth)` should work.  If worksheet then one would need to add the sheet to which it is scoped: `For Each Cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(currMonth)`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand the concept of objects in Excel

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax for your `mes` function. Only make it *Public* if it's called from another code module.

```
Private Function mes(refMonth As Integer) As String
    'Returns the month in full
    Dim months As Variant
    months = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "December")
    mes = months(refMonth - 1)
End Function
```

`For Each Cell In [currMonth]`  presumes that `currMonth` is a range. Therefore replace `[currMonth]' with a range, like` ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D30")`

It appears that you have a table in your project. If so, try this:-

```
Dim Tbl         As ListObject

Set Tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
For Each Cell In Tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(8)
```

Here the range is defined as the 8th column of the table.

Finally, don't `Select` or `Activate` anything. Selecting and Activating are things the user needs, Excel doesn't. Therefore you might activate or select something as you hand control back to the user.

In place of

```
Sheets("Calendar").Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(3, "A").Select
status = ActiveCell.Value
```

Just use

```
status = Sheets("Calendar").Cells(3, "A").Value
or
status =  Sheets("Calendar").Range(A3").Value
```

You will find it expedient to use the syntax for addressing ranges when you address a range of several cells but use the syntax for addressing cells when you wish to address a single cell. Address a cell as `Worksheets("SheetName").Cells([Row number], [Column number])` where the column name may be given instead of the column number if you find it easier to read (it's more difficult to calculate).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it really is much more concise.
But in my case, I need my spreadsheet to be activated, to guarantee the reference (the calendar is in another spreadsheet), after that I select the line below to call the function that will format my cell

Comment: Any way to avoid having to take the user to the calendar sheet whenever I run the call?

Comment: Excel knows exactly where `Worksheets("MyCalendar").Range("A2"A30")` is whether you activate that sheet or another. As you say, the point is what you want the user to see. If you activate that sheet he will see it. He doesn't need to see it for Excel to find a cell on it. Vision and action aren't related. Excel can act without the user seeing the object. Bear in mind that whatever action you take - read or write - takes place in the computer's memory, not on the screen which gets the information 2nd hand: VBA sets the memory, the memory sets the screen.

Comment: In fact, output to the screen is similar to output to a printer. In reverse, when you select something on the screen the CPU matches the screen area to a storage location in the ROM. VBA accesses the ROM directly and then synchs with what's on the screen. For large operations it's useful to turn off synching entirely until all is done, saving 60% of the time a program needs to run. The `Selection` object was created to communicate the user's clicks & keyboard strokes to Excel's memory. VBA doesn't need it.